# Linq find what happens underneath- Search

Tags: c#, linq

I have very limited experience with LINQ and wanted to understand how this piece of code grabs the value. Does it do a search in entire list or hits the exact record in the list due to `alternateId = Names.ElementAt(n).` It looks like a 'Where clause' to me in SQL. But this may be different.

Just trying to understand the cost of full list search if that is whats happening

```
MapList.Find(x => x.AlternateId == Names.ElementAt(n).ToString()).MyColumValue;
```

Comment: Whether `Names.ElementAt` has to enumerate over n elements depends on the type of collection `Names` is. If `Names` implements IList, then it references the element directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Find(Predicate<T>)` **is not** part of LINQ, but it's a method of the generic collection type `List<T>`. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8), it performs linear search until the first element that matches the predicate is found.

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is Count.

---

The LINQ method `Names.ElementAt(n)` is either O(1) or O(n) depending on the type of `Names`. If it's implementing `IList<T>` (thus supporting random access), it's O(1). Else `ElementAt` enumerates `Names` until the n<sup>th</sup> element was returned.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, since Find does a linear search, I am looking for a better way to do this operation such that the linear search be not performed. Is there another better way to look up the maplist item where that criteria is met. I wont know where in the list the element exists else I would have element (n) on maplist too. But I have to do a search on it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

initially, data from MapList is initialized to be x, then look for AlternateID where it has the same value as Names.ElementAt(n) then return the result as string.

Answer (score 1):

The call `Names.ElementAt(n)` finds the exact record because its being looked up by an Index.

The call `MapList.Find(x => x.AlternateId = ...` will search the entire list and then return the first occurrence.

I think the answer will be clearer if you modify the code to something hardcoded (just to understand the workings). Modify `Names.ElementAt(n).ToString()` to something else ("4" may be)

So,

`MapList.Find(x => x.AlternateId == Names.ElementAt(n).ToString()).MyColumValue;`

becomes

`MapList.Find(x => x.AlternateId == "4").MyColumValue;`